# Original script directory in PHP

Tags: php

Magic constant  `__DIR__`  is the directory of the current script, but what if I need the directory of the script that included or required it, i.e., the original script? Is there something like a `__ORIGINALDIR__`?

In particular, if the directory of the current script equals the directory of the original script then we should get `__ORIGINALDIR__ === __DIR__`.

Comment: `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
echo dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: That's useful, although not exactly what I meant, I have clarified the question now.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Really? What were the result you received?

Comment: You server could be a shared server without any `/var/www`